# iOS Swift - Is it possible to query a SPARQL endpoint in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to build an iOS (iPhone or iPad) application where I can query a SPARQL endpoint and results returned will be printed in a a new window. I'm planning to code in either Swift or Objective-C.

My questions are:

1. Can I query a SPARQL endpoint using Swift/Objective-C?
2. If so, are there any tutorials on how to do it?
3. Do I have to import any packages into XCode just like how we do in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

It's just an HTTP request. Doing it with curl from the command line would be something like

```
curl "http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?query=SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 3"
```

or, escaped to work better with curl,

```
curl http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?query=SELECT%20%2A%20WHERE%20%7B%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%7D%20LIMIT%203
```

This will get the result in XML, but you could add an Accept header to request JSON, CSV, or TSV instead.

So, while there may be add-in libraries library to automate some of the communication with the SPARQL endpoint, all you really need is the ability to do remote HTTP requests.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm very new to iOS programming. So can you please show me a sample code of Swift/Objective-C on how to use a HTTP request?

Comment: I've never done any iOS development, but a Google search for "objective c" "http request" gets plenty of hits.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that. I'm trying to code in Swift, not Objective-C.